# How to sort a nested array in descending order? - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, laravel-5

Im trying to sort a nested array. I've tried using rsort function `$sort = rsort($json->likes);` but I keep getting an error that read: `Attempt to modify property of non-object`.

My array looks like:

```
array:1 [▼
  "records" => array:268 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "AC/DC"
      "fb_likes" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 20101
          "account_id" => 1
          "facebook_id" => "1"
          "likes" => 30269844
          "talking_about_count" => 83859
          "created_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
          "updated_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
        ]
        1 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 16654
          "account_id" => 1
          "facebook_id" => "1"
          "likes" => 30269844
          "talking_about_count" => 83859
          "created_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
          "updated_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Hugh Jackman"
      "fb_likes" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 20102
          "account_id" => 2
          "facebook_id" => "2"
          "likes" => 22347519
          "talking_about_count" => 724650
          "created_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
          "updated_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
        ]
        1 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 16655
          "account_id" => 2
          "facebook_id" => "2"
          "likes" => 22347519
          "talking_about_count" => 724650
          "created_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
          "updated_at" => "2016-03-20 10:43:27"
        ]
      ]
    ]
]
```

I need to sort the array by the number of latest created_at date "likes".

Note: Im using laravel 5.2 and the array is returned as json.

Comment: Try $sort = rsort($json['likes']);

Comment: tried it. I get an error that reads `rsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`.

Comment: Are you sure your `$json['likes']` has data?

Comment: Yes if I `dd( );` the result I see the array as posted in the question.